# Django , django-comments-xtd: update template variable/object without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

This question might look silly, as i know Once the page have been rendered, all template variables disappear. As per below code i am loading comments for an video object vid, as soon as i load a new video say vid_1 into the player i wanna load comments for vid_1 without refreshing page

```
    <script>
function loadComments(){
  window.comments_props = {% get_commentbox_props for vid %};
  </script>
```

any method to do so , can anyone help me ?

Comment: Looks like a React/Angular solution will solve your problem.

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos thank you.

Comment: you re welcome @Prithviraj Mane